# Linear types in lean?

Tags: lean, linear-type

Is the LEAN type checker able to count the number of times a parameter is used in a function body?

In Idris2 for comparison I might use `(1 x:Nat)` which then makes sure my function uses x exactly once.  Or I might write `(0 pf: x < 5)` to make sure the parameter gets erased.  In LEAN can I force the type checker to counter uses?

---

Seems `linear-type` is not a tag yet and I haven't the points needed to create a tag, happy to have a power user edit that.

Comment: Done! You can edit the tag wiki if you like.

Comment: I’m not aware of anything like that, so I think the answer is no, but I see here Leo mentioning that this is a planned future addition to Lean (https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Issue.20using.20a.20Type.201.20in.20forIn/near/277961983).  That was over a year ago, so I’ll let a more knowledgeable person answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the type checker implements a theory that does not have any substructural types in it. You can implement this as an after-the-fact checker though, by analyzing the term to see where it has been used.

Comment: True, but I'd like to use it within proofs, to prove an algorithm uses resources according to plan.  An after-the-fact checker won't interact with other proofs in LEAN I suspect.

Comment: It can, your after the fact checker can produce proofs of its own which interact with other proofs produced by the checker to get whole program correctness statements. It's a project, though, people usually write masters theses about this kind of thing.